# get clients byte encoding from c# server application

Tags: c#, tcp

I have a TCP server in C# that accepts clients and prints their data to the console.

To read the data and write it to the console I currently use this:

```
data = new byte[1024];
recv = client.Receive(data);
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv));
```

This method works for when I connect in Hercules TCP Client, Telnet, and other programs. However, when using my PSP to send a string, it does not display. The PSP strings appear in other TCP Server applications, but it will not read with the code I am using above.

How can I read the type of encoding that is being received from the PSP and set it to the Encoding in my C# Server?

Perhaps I am looking in the wrong direction: Here is the core of my program: http://pastebin.com/ZKTfJV1u

Comment: what is a PSP? and why would expect anyone to know that with only a C# tag?

Comment: Playstation Portable. It's not really relevant, I just need to know how to read the type of encoding from a client instead of already defining it.

Comment: The client should only send plain text data to be visible on the console, otherwise you'll only see garbage. Looking for a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) could help if present. If not, UTF-8 seems to be the most reliable guess nowadays, both in being commonly used and giving backwards compatibility to ASCII.

Comment: @Alejandro I've tried UTF-8 to no avail. Is there a program I can use to connect to and send a byte and for it to show me the BOM or type of data that is being sent from my socket? Otherwise I do not know how to find this out.

Comment: wireshark or Microsoft Network Monitor for raw network traffic

Comment: But are you sure that the PSP is sending *only* plain text? I find it difficult.

Comment: @JJS The string I was attempting to send from the PSP to my server (10.1.1.5) was "laser<eof"> These are the results I gained from wireshark. 
1: http://i.imgur.com/Q0DHwhR.png
2: http://i.imgur.com/SWkelEM.png

malformed packet? this must be the issue?

Comment: @JJS I changed the port from 5000 which was causing the GSM error, now there is no error, and in fact this is the raw data: http://gyazo.com/a5ca8ac1e0c594370989096e7fe04b0b

Comment: @Alejandro This is the raw data I captured http://gyazo.com/a5ca8ac1e0c594370989096e7fe04b0b It still does not come up in my server.

Comment: @Alejandro http://gyazo.com/ab035dc86d7bfd79ca00e4958deaaf4a Binary Large Object?